# How to receive the struct sent over UDP from python , in esp8266

Tags: python, sockets, arduino, udp, esp8266

I am sending UDP packets from my computer to esp8266, but after receiving the packet, it looks something like this in the Arduino serial monitor:
[image]

The original data i am sending:
[image]

Here is the block of code for the receiving end (esp8266):

```
void udp_rcv()
{
  int packetSize = UDP.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet! Size: ");
    Serial.println(packetSize); 
    int len = UDP.read(packet, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      packet[len] = '\0';
    }
    Serial.print("Packet received: ");
    Serial.println(packet[0]);
}
```

And this is the code sending the UDP packet from my pc using python:

```
pygame.event.pump()
roll     = mapping(joystick.get_axis(0),-1,1,1000,2000)
pitch    = mapping(joystick.get_axis(1),1,-1,1000,2000)
yaw      = mapping(joystick.get_axis(2),-1,1,1000,2000)
throttle = mapping(joystick.get_axis(3),1,-1,1000,2000)
mode     = joystick.get_button(6)

# Be sure to always send the data as floats
# The extra zeros on the message are there in order for the other scripts to do not complain about missing information
message = [roll, pitch, yaw, throttle, mode, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
buf = struct.pack('>' + 'd' * len(message), *message)
sock.sendto(buf, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print( message)
```

All I am trying to do is use my Joystick gamepad inputs to send it to the esp8266 via UDP protocol

Comment: Do you have a specific question? The code you posted doesn't appear to try to decode the contents of the UDP packet. You're just printing out the first byte of the packet - what do you expect to see? Also please don't post images when you can post text. Copy and paste the text into the question. Images aren't searchable and people with visual difficulties often cannot read them.

Comment: @romkey, how can I print the whole float array I am sending as a packet? please tell.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask the question that you’re asking. That will help other people who use the site.

Comment: @romkey sir please help now , i have edited the question

Comment: Your receiving code is not decoding the packet. On the sending side, `struct.pack` is converting a list of floats into a byte string. You are presumably successfully sending that message to the peer, who is (apparently) successfully receiving it. However, you need to reverse the `struct.pack` operation to convert it from a byte string back to a list/array of floats in whatever format your receiving language expects. If the receiving side were using python, you could use `struct.unpack` for that. It's not clear what language you are using, but it probably has an equivalent library function.

Comment: How do you know that the ESP8266 isn't receiving the packet? I have calculated that the first byte of the number 1500 encoded as a double is 0x40, which is the ASCII code for @. So it seems to be working. The computer is doing what you told it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send and receive data across different platforms, you need to aware of the data type and data structure that you are sending as well as the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of both the sender and the receiver.

### Regarding your Python code

I'm not sure why you explicitly specify big endian with `>` for packing the data, most of the modern computers are using little endian rather than big endian (unless you had a Motorola 68000 or PowerPC machine), furthermore all the MCU such as Uno and ESP8266 are little endian MCU. So it would be make more sense to specify little endian with `<` to pack your data.

Secondly, you are assuming your data are in `double` but if you look at screen shot on `message`, `mode` is definitely not a `double` but an `int` (on most of modern PCs, `int` is 32-bit long).

So instead of packing your data with:

```py
buf = struct.pack('>' + 'd' * len(message), *message)
```

What you should really do is:

```py
buf = struct.pack('<ddddiddddddddd', *message)
```

### Regarding your Arduino Code

The data sending from the Python code is a series of bytes that can be represented in C++ as:

```cpp
struct __attribute__((packed)) JoyStick {
  double roll;
  double pitch;
  double yaw;
  double throttle;
  int32_t mode;
  double array[9]; 
};
```

Since the packet data is an array of `uint8_t` (or `char` as you might declared), it will be easier to copy the data into a variable of `JoyStick_t` type, so that you can access the data as a `struct`.

```
  int packetSize = UDP.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.printf("Received %d bytes\n", packetSize);
    if (UDP.read(packet, packetSize) > 0)) {
      JoyStick myJoystick;                      //create a struct
      memcpy(&myJoystick, packet, packetSize);  //copy packet array to the a struct
      Serial.printf("%f %f %f %f %d\n", 
                    myJoystick.roll, 
                    myJoystick.pitch, 
                    myJoystick.yaw, 
                    myJoystick.throttle, 
                    myJoystick.mode);           // access the data in the struct
    }
  }
```